# Appcelerator Studio stalls when trying to browse to a file

Tags: macos, appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

My appcelerator studio and Mac stalls everytime when I want to browse to import a project, or open a file.

I'm using Appcelerator Studio 4.7.0.20..... on my Mac 10.11.6 with Java 7 installed.

I have to hard reset my mac when hitting the browse button.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways you can import your projects into Appcelerator Studio.

1. Drag-and-drop your project into Project Explorer empty area - here, you will find two options - either linking or copying your project into workspace
2. Go to File ->Import -> General ->Existing projects into Workspace

I hope one of them will help you to import your project.

However, issue is similar to this - https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-7851. Can you provide more details on the environment and exact reproducible case in the ticket, so that issue will be addressed soon.